# Why response body not compressed when use webtestclient?

Tags: compression, gzip, response, resttemplate, webtestclient

I use WebTestClient writing test cases in spring boot application. I need to get response body by compressing it. When I use RestTemplate I can get compressed response body.

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        httpHeaders.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);`

HttpEntity<RequestDTO> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestDTO, httpHeaders);
esponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(baseURL + "/test",HttpMethod.POST,      requestEntity, byte[].class);
```

When I use WebTestClient, response body not compressed. Is there any way to compressed response body when use WebTestClient.

```
byte[] response = webTestClient.post().uri("/test")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestDTO)).exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(byte[].class)
                .returnResult().getResponseBody();
```